# HTML::FormHandler dynamic fields added client side

Tags: perl, forms, catalyst

I'm using [HTML::FormHandler](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::FormHandler) and I would like to have a form that has a dynamic number of form elements. Essentially, I have some inputs that are always present, such as `first_name`, `last_name`, and `email`, but then I have an input, `pracitce_area`, that I can have many of dynamically (so `practice_area1`, `pracitce_area2`, etc). So on the client side I will be using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) to dynamically add more `practice_area` inputs, and I would like for my HTML::FormHandler form to be able to process a dynamic number of these inputs and validate them and put them in the database. The `practice_area` inputs will be stored in a separate table that will be related with a foreign key to the element of this form, so I would like for HTML::FormHandler to know that these are related and pull out a dynamic number when editing, but also be able to save a dynamic number into the database when saving. Is there a way to handle something like this with `HTML::FormHandler`? Here's the definition of my form:

```
package test::Form::Base;
use namespace::autoclean;
use HTML::FormHandler::Moose;
with 'HTML::FormHandler::TraitFor::Model::DBIC';    

has title => ( is => 'ro', default => 'Client Information Form');
has '+item_class' => ( default => 'ClientInformationForm' );

has_field 'first_name' => (
    type         => 'Text',
    label => 'First Name',
    required => 1,
);

has_field 'last_name' => (
    type         => 'Text',
    label => 'Last Name',
    required => 1,
);

has_field 'email' => (
    type         => 'Email',
    label => 'Email',
    required => 1,
);

#would like to have this be dynamic in number, and have HTML::FormHandler know 
#that it's related with a foreign key when pulling them out of the database
has_field 'practice_area' => (
    type         => 'TextArea',
);
no HTML::FormHandler::Moose;
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [HTML::Formhandler::Repeatable](http://search.cpan.org/~gshank/HTML-FormHandler-0.40055/lib/HTML/FormHandler/Field/Repeatable.pm).

You should just be able to use `practice_area` in your form and have multiple entries. These will just be pulled in an an array(ref) in form processing.

Comment: great! Exactly what I was looking for.